# Do ~ば conditionals have temporal requirements (in comparison to ~なら)?

Tags: conditionals

I know that ~なら sentences are often provided as examples of Japanese conditionals which *don't* have temporal requirements. Thus,

> AならB
>
> (1) 乗る**なら**飲むな
>
> (1) If it's the case that you're driving, don't drink (beforehand)!

makes sense even though A happens after B, literally speaking.

**Question:** Grammatically, could it *also* make sense to say

> (2) 乗**れば**飲むな

in Japanese to mean "don't drink before driving"? Or would saying it this way instead imply　something like "if one drives, don't drink *afterward* (either *while* driving, or *after* driving)"? **Generally, what exactly is the difference between (1) and (2)?**

I ask this because I'm under the impression that

> (3) 乗る**なら**飲むな

is an informal way of saying

> (4) 乗る**ならば**飲むな

where ならば is *already* a ば-conditional (of the copula):

> (5) 乗る**のであれば**飲むな

That is, semantically don't (3), (4), and (5) all mean the exact same thing as each other (despite having different levels of formality)?

This leads me to believe that -ば, strictly speaking, must *not* have a temporal requirement?

Comment: 乗れば飲むな somehow sounds to me like 'if you get in the car, don't drink (after that)'

Comment: 乗れば飲むな is not a natural sentence to begin with.

Comment: Probably one of these will answer [Is it ever right to use ば conditional to mean 'when'?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29495) / [Differences among -たら, なら, -と, -んだったら, -ば, etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/393)